# Retrive data by comparing relational data's last records status value

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I have following tables Each customer has multiple followups

### Schema

[image: Schema Image]

### Data

[image: Data image]

and wanted to retrieve customerslist
where
`Followups.attendedDate > customer.attendedDate`
and where
`[last for customer] Followup.statusid=2 or 7 or 8 or 9`

### Code I did

```
    Dim Result As List(Of Customer)
                                
    Result = Await db.Customers.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.AttendedDate).Include(Function(x) x.FollowUps.Select(Function(y) y.CallStatu)).Where(Function(x) x.AttendedBy IsNot Nothing And x.FollowUps.Any(Function(z) z.StatusID = 2 Or z.StatusID = 7 Or z.StatusID = 8 Or z.StatusID = 9)).Where(Function(x) x.FollowUps.Where(Function(y) y.AttendedDate > x.AttendedDate).Count > 0).ToListAsync
                            
    Dim RemoveList As New List(Of Customer)
    For Each cust As Customer In Result
        If cust.FollowUps.Last.StatusID <> 2 And cust.FollowUps.Last.StatusID <> 7 And cust.FollowUps.Last.StatusID <> 8 cust.FollowUps.Last.StatusID <> 9 Then
            RemoveList.Add(cust)
        End If
    Next
    
    For Each Cust As Customer In RemoveList
        Result.Remove(Cust)
    Next
```

Query gives me the result as customerlist where customers has status among all his statuses where criteria of statusID = 2|7|8|9 matches. I want customers only with a last statusID=2|7|8|9 among his all status.

So, in given sample data Customer Steve should be in result list as his last status is followup(2). Customer John Should not be in list as it has no followups. Customer Mark also should not be in result list as among his all status his last/latest status is NotInterested(1)

TIA

Comment: So what have you tried and what happened when you tried it? SO is not a place for questions of the form "I want to do X, tell me how".

Comment: Without any code we can't give an answer as we don't know for example the class you are using for your context.  Also you say you want to retrieve customers but don't specify which Followups.attendedDate the customer.attendedDate has to be after - the first, the last, any? I'd guess you mean the most recent, is that right?  What if the customer has no attended date?  And what if there is but there's no follow ups?  Please help us to help you by defining the problem clearly and providing some attempt at your code so we've somewhere to start.

Answer (score 0):

See my comment on your original question for provisos & reservations about this answer.  I have assumed you are testing for customers where any of the follow-ups have a date later than customer attended date.  You can take this structure and use it as a basis to change the test if needed.

So, try something like this:

```
    Using db As New YourContext
        Dim Customers = db.Customer.Where(Function(c) c.FollowUp.Any(Function(f) f.attendedDate  > c.attendedDate)).ToList()
         ... now do something with the result
    End Using
```

UPDATE - to code added in comments.

I can't test this as I don't have access to your database, but try something like this:

```
        Dim AllowedStatus = New List(Of Integer)({2, 7, 8})
        Result = Await db.Customers.Where(Function(c) c.AttendedBy IsNot Nothing 
                                                      AndAlso c.FollowUps.OrderBy(Function(f) f.attendedDate).LastOrDefault() IsNot Nothing 
                                                      AndAlso AllowedStatus.Contains(c.FollowUps.OrderBy(Function(f) f.attendedDate).LastOrDefault().StatusID) 
                                                      AndAlso c.FollowUps.Any(Function(f) f.attendedDate > c.AttendedDate ).ToListAsync()
```

or maybe better, change:

```
AndAlso c.FollowUps.OrderBy(Function(f) f.attendedDate).LastOrDefault() IsNot Nothing
```

into

```
AndAlso c.FollowUps.Any()
```

Just to test there are any follow ups to test

Comment: it gives me all follow ups i just need last one, per customerID. If statusID= 2 or 4

Comment: It doesn't give follow ups, it gives Customers and now you've changed your definition by adding status Id.  If you've tried it, you must have some code, so amend your original question to add the code and include a full definition of what you are trying to do and then I'll see if I can amend my answer accordingly.

Comment: Result = Await db.Customers.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.AttendedDate).Include(Function(x) x.FollowUps.Select(Function(y) y.CallStatu)).Where(Function(x) x.AttendedBy IsNot Nothing And x.FollowUps.Any(Function(z) z.StatusID = 2 Or z.StatusID = 7 Or z.StatusID = 8)).Where(Function(x) x.FollowUps.Where(Function(y) y.AttendedDate > x.AttendedDate).Count > 0).ToListAsync

Comment: Following is my code, I need a list of customers includes follow ups where followups.attendeddate > customer.attendeddate and last followup for customer must be with certain statusid(eg. 2) Thanks

Comment: It's better to amend your original question to add code.  Adding code in comments makes it difficult to read and hides it from others who may be able to help with your original question.  I have amended my answer with and updated suggestion

Comment: I have updated my question with more description please have a look TIA